# When doing replaygain on multi-disc albums, should the "album" gain actually be a "disc" gain?

Tags: music, replaygain

I am writing a script to add replaygain tags to my entire music library, and it is working well. However, I am wondering what the correct behavior is for calculating album (or "audiophile") gain values for things like multi-disc albums. Should I calculate one gain value for the entire album, or should I calculate a different value for each disc (or comparable subunit) within the album?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the album set.  If they're designed to be a single, cohesive work, then Album Gain across all discs makes more sense.  If they're just collections of tracks, then Album Gain on each individual disc.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on whether you're going to be listening to the tracks on each of the discs all at once, or one disc at a time.

If you're going to be playing the tracks one disc at a time, then calculate 'Album Gain' across each of the discs separately.  If you're going to be playing the tracks from the entire set of discs in one session, then you'll want volume adjustments to be relative to the entire set--i.e. calculate Album Gain for the entire set of tracks.

I'd personally go with the latter approach.